# data from youtube not passed using delegate

Tags: swift, delegates

I want to retrieve data from youtube from home controller and pass my data to my video controller, but the data it's not being transfer into my video controller. but the data it's there in the home controller when I try to print it. this is my code

this is my protocol I put above home controller class

```
protocol VideoListDelegate: class {
    func didAddVideoItem(results: [SearchResult])
}
```

and this is my instance delegate in my home controller class

```
weak var delegate: VideoListDelegate?
```

this is my api called in home controller

```
private func youtubeAPI(with query: Method) {
    let request = SearchListRequest(part: [.id, .snippet], maxResults: 50, searchQuery: query.rawValue)

    ApiSession.shared.send(request) { (results) in
        if let err = results.error {
            print(" -- Failed to get data -- ")
            print(" -- \(err) -- ")
            return
        }

        if let result = results.value?.items {
            self.delegate?.didAddVideoItem(results: result)
        }

        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        let searchVideoController = VideoController(collectionViewLayout: layout)

        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(searchVideoController, animated: true)
    }
}
```

and then I conform my video controller with my protocol

```
class VideoController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, VideoListDelegate {

// Add video into video array
func didAddVideoItem(results: [SearchResult]) {
    for item in results {
        print(item.snippet.title)

        let video = Video(title: item.snippet.title, videoId: item.id.videoID ?? "")
        self.videos.append(video)
    }

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.collectionView.reloadData()
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @JarvisTheAvenger the home controller?

Comment: why don't you pass it through video view controller instance

Comment: like doing `searchVideoController.results = results`

Comment: if results are nil or empty still your navigation is getting called.

Comment: @JarvisTheAvenger it work so, actually I didn't have to using delegate after all

Comment: Great!!! Updated answer accordingly!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your API method should be like this then you won't need delegation to pass the data:

```
private func youtubeAPI(with query: Method) {
    let request = SearchListRequest(part: [.id, .snippet], maxResults: 50, searchQuery: query.rawValue)

    ApiSession.shared.send(request) { (results) in
        if let err = results.error {
            print(" -- Failed to get data -- ")
            print(" -- \(err) -- ")
            return
        }

        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        let searchVideoController = VideoController(collectionViewLayout: layout)
        searchVideoController.results = results.value?.items ?? []
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(searchVideoController, animated: true)
    }
}
```

And in your VideoViewController add one variable `results` of type `[SearchResult]`.